# Using firebase for personal projects. Is there a risk of bills and how to avoid them?

Tags: javascript, reactjs, firebase

I ma looking to do a course and a a tutorial form youtube.

This project more specifically as it has a lot of features I would like to learn and my back-end knowledge is very basic currently.

[Project][1]
https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=m_u6P5k0vP0&t=584s

Since the video was released firebase plans have changed and you read tales of huge bills.

Is there a way to avoid this? and if anyone knows the project will I be safe from billing whilst building it?  The project will never be published anywhere, just used by me for practise and testing which seems fine as the limits for free users are quite big.  I just have some fear from reading horror stories of accidental loops and the like!

Any help or advice on this is welcome

Comment: Why would this be downvoted? Out of curiosity

Comment: Likely because you used "Any help or advice", your question is too broad and the question is not related to a specific programming issue which leads to "Opinions" rather than "Answers". This type of query is better suited to a chat room, forum or to the [Firebase Slack](https://firebase.community) rather than StackOverflow.

Answer (score 1):

I don't think you should be worried about racking up huge bills if you're not going to publish the project anywhere and if you're on the free plan they literally can't bill you. even if you decide the project is really cool and you want to publish it you won't have to use their other plans unless for specific reasons (like cloud functions for example). So basically don't worry it's a really good platform to help with your development. I myself have done tons of projects where I used firebase in the backend and it's been great.

Comment: Thank you, I will need cloud functions for the project so I will have to use the paid plan. I’m pretty confident it should be fine but just from reading a few horror stories I was a little concerned!

Comment: Well if these projects aren't gonna be that big you can still use cloud functions for free if you use node version 8 instead of 10 but that will be deprecated by September this year I think so be carefull